# large digital multiplier IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, multiplier

I was in college 18 years ago and saw a classmate's project that had a very large DIP IC on it (roughly 1"x4" !) which he said was a digital multiplier IC. (I assume it was 32x32 -> 64) I'm curious what part that might have been and was wondering if anyone might be able to help me find it.

Comment: [TRW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRW) used to make parallel mutipliers in DIP ICs, eg the long obsolete 016HJ1C 16 X 16 part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few companies made stand alone digital multipliers.  A long time ago I used one from Weitek (might be spelled differently).  If I remember there were two other competing products we considered at the time.  One was from Honeywell, but I'm not sure that ever made it to the market.  I think the third was Analog Devices.

I designed a 3D graphics processor in the mid to early 1980s that used a floating point multiplier and adder.  These were both large DIP chips.  Both had effectively a 5 stage pipeline if I remember right.  I put a very basic sequential controller around them so we could do things like divide, square root, sin, cos, etc by using microcode.

Comment: thanks! Looks like the Weitek WTL1232 might have been it: about 0.8" x 3.2" http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Weitek/WTL1232.pdf

Comment: Wow, 750mW *standby* power! Definitely the 80s :-)

Answer (score 6):

[TRW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRW_Inc.#Semiconductors_and_computers) made multipliers such as this 16 X 16 part :-

[image: TRW1016]

or this, which would be over 3" long!

[image]